# IN GCP Is a hub & spoke model with vpc peering better compared to using a shared vpc

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, firewall

Q1: Is a hub & spoke model with vpc peering better compared to using a shared vpc. See below tenancy design in AWS, we are trying to bring a similar structure.[image]

Q2: Is there any native service/virtual appliance(Firewall) or feature available to route traffic between spokes without spoke to spoke peering?

Q3: Cross account access – Is it possible to have cross-account access

Q4: Do we use Subnet to create zones in GCP, refer diagram above

Q5: Is there randomization of the zones in GCP as in AWS (Zone a in one account would be Zone b in another)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Q2: Is there any native service/virtual appliance(Firewall) or feature available to route traffic between spokes without spoke to spoke peering?

No, the VPC peering is not transitive in nature. This means that VPC A peered with VPC B,  VPC A peered with VPC C would mean that VPC B cannot see or send ICMP traffic to VPC C.

> Q3: Cross account access – Is it possible to have cross-account access

Yes, as long as there is a peering is established between all communicating accounts

> Q4: Do we use Subnet to create zones in GCP, refer diagram above

Availability zones in AWS and Zones in GCP are comparable. Subnet's are further slicing down the VPC to create dedicated areas for inbound/outbound traffic management and resources placements

> Q5: Is there randomization of the zones in GCP as in AWS (Zone a in one account would be Zone b in another)

Yes the zones are randomized in GCP and do not represent fixed or known locations all the times.

Answer (score 0):

```
Q1: Is a hub & spoke model with vpc peering better compared to using a shared vpc. See below tenancy design in AWS, we are trying to bring a similar structure.
```

Regarding Q1, the merits of the solution depend on the features accounted for the suitability of the solution, that would be different for each case.

There are two approaches for this hub-and-spoke architecture: shared VPC and peered VPC.

Shared VPC [1] allows one organization to connect resources from multiple projects to a common VPC network, so that they can communicate with each other securely and efficiently using internal IPs from that network. There will be:

A host project
One or more other service projects attached to it

VPC Network Peering [2] allows private connectivity across two VPC networks which may belong to one or multiple projects or organizations.

---

[1] https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/shared-vpc

[2] https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering

Answer (score 0):

I know it's old but needs a correction:
Q2 - yes, you can route between spokes via hub VPC if you have a routing VM in hub and a proper custom route via that VM. Hub needs to export custom routes and spokes need to import. Pretty standard design for threat inspection between VPCs.